# Need a popup with a multiline textbox

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I would like my program to pop up a box in which the user can enter text to store it in a database, this will happen every time a user exits a record .This text will have a length up to 100 characters. Is there a component for this functionality or is there an approach to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a new form, slap a TMemo there and maybe a pair of Ok/Cancel buttons, set the memo MaxLength to 100 and ShowModal the form. It should be trivial, try it.